# Log file for each execution of a script with filename as the execution order

Tags: python, logging

I want create a log scheme for a script where each run generates a log  file. Example:

Run 1 -> 1.log

Run 2 -> 2.log

...

Run N -> N.log

What kind of handler can I use?

Comment: You might want to have a look at `logging.handlers.BaseRotatingHandler`  with a custom `rotator` : https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.BaseRotatingHandler

Comment: Found a implementation of the behavior in Apache Airflow source code. I'm working with the adaptation without the airflow dag contexts and works like a charm.

Comment: @CaioBelfort It would be great if you could share your findings with some code :-)

Comment: @norok2 Look at this file https://github.com/caiobelfort/log_utils/blob/master/log_utils/handlers.py